# laravel 5.5 billing set short trial period for testing recurring

Tags: laravel, billing

Testing laravel 5.5 and  cashier.

Wnant very short trial period for testing recurring payments and webhooks.

In documentation example trial period setting only for days:

```
$user->newSubscription('main', 'monthly')
        ->trialDays(10)
        ->create($creditCardToken);
```

How i can set trial for a seconds or minute ??

Answer (score 2):

You can use [trailUntil](https://github.com/laravel/cashier/blob/58efad0548d307426be6d4efbba0193f49285408/src/SubscriptionBuilder.php#L112):

```
$user->newSubscription('main', 'monthly')
    ->trialUntil(Carbon::now()->addSecounds(60))
    ->create($creditCardToken);
```

Answer (score 0):

As a common practice of online applications has mostly in Days is a minimum subscription time, setting mins and seconds not a sense in this fact. As well as in laravel cashier is not provide method `trialInMins`. You can take a look on the **SubscriptionBuilder** class https://github.com/laravel/cashier/blob/58efad0548d307426be6d4efbba0193f49285408/src/SubscriptionBuilder.php#L99

Still, you can try `trialUntil` with **Carbon** object with time